# angular routing to old asp.net app on the same server

Tags: asp.net, angular, url, routes

So the url for my angular web app is https://devnet/appName/ and when I click a button I want it to go to http://devnet.some.org/appName/page.aspx.  now here's the part I need help with, the angular web app is on devnet, testnet and (you guess it) prodnet.  depending upon which server the angular app is running from is where I want it to go and find the old app.

- https://devnet/appName/route ->
  http://devnet.some.org/appName/page.aspx
- https://testnet/appName/route ->
  http://testnet.some.org/appName/page.aspx
- https://prodnet/appName/route ->
  http://prodnet.some.org/appName/page.aspx

Notice the change in protocol, the servers are the same as is the appName, but the route and page.aspx will be different.

And yes this is a temporary thing until the angular app is completely complete

Answer (score 0):

The best approach from my POV is to use environments, e.g.:

```
environment.ts // current one
environment.dev.ts
environment.test.ts
environment.prod.ts
```

Add corresponding configurations in angular.json (propagate "production" configuration).

Add `oldUrl` to the environment interface and provide different values for each particular environment.

Import environment to the component where you the redirect button is used and use `environment.oldUrl` property to construct a proper redirect URL.